# Jenkins error - Use a tool from a predefined Tool Installation -- EgsonarQube Scanner

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm a total noob with Jenkins and bitbucket. I'm trying to deploy a bitbucket branch in Jenkins, but I keep getting a failure with the following message in Stage logs:

```
 Error: Error while performing Quality Gates validation! Analysis Id is null"
```

In addition, in the stage logs, I see the following message:

```
 Use a tool from a predefined Tool Installation -- EgsonarQube Scanner

 Unpacking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar- 
 scanner-cli/2.6.1/sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.zip to
```

/users/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/EgsonarQube_Scanner on jenkins-centos-he-slave-xjcvm

The process I'm following is:

1. Do a git push origin  to bitbucket.
2. Do a pull request in bitbucket on the branch, merging to Master.
3. Go into jenkins, which automatically runs the deploy script on the branch.

Has someone else run into this and how did y'all solve it?

Comment: It will be difficult to answer without looking how Jenkins job is configured. Can you share more details on that?

Comment: @saurabh14292 - the entire jenkins CICD pipeline configuration is done by a different team and I have no insight into it. All I know is jenkins and bitbucket are so configured that as soon as I push my local branch to bitbucket repo and start a pull request to merge into master, jenkins starts the build process. After that, I go into jenkins and select the environment I want to deploy into (staging, prod), check deploy and run it. The failure is occuring at that stage with the error I describe in my original post. If you have any specific questions, I can try to get those answers. thanks,

Comment: As far as the logs you have posted, I can see you are doing SonarQube analysis. Either using Jenkins Plugin or through Maven. Is there anything else on logs? Any more errors before job fails?My guess is that for some reason, integration between SonarQube is failing, can't say why without having a look at more logs or the way it is configured.